# Javascript new Date(); output

Tags: javascript

Hello so I am making a clock could anyone tell me what the output of current would be
at midnight(00:00) and midday(12:00) ? and also the output of 13:00 in the afternoon and 01:00 at night?
thank you in advance!

```js
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var current = hours + (minutes * .01);
console.log(current);
```

i did try adding a few hours to the hour var with + to test but the output was giving odd times such as 26:00

Comment: Can't you test it yourself?

Comment: I'm struggling to find a problem to solve here, what's the _actual_ issue you're facing?

Comment: @Justinas i don't know how to i did try adding a few hour to the time but then i got times like 26:00

Comment: Add that to your question, that's an actual problem I can solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test yourself by passing a specific date string into the `new Date()` call. You can see more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours#using_gethours)

```js
var date = new Date('May 4, 2021 7:00:00')
var hours =  date.getHours()
var minutes =  date.getMinutes()
var seconds = date.getSeconds()

function showPrettyTime (hours, minutes, seconds) {
  if (hours < 10) {
    hours = '0' + hours
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = '0' + minutes
  }
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = '0' + seconds
  }
  var prettyDate = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds
  console.log(prettyDate)
}


showPrettyTime(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a `testDate()` function for you. You can see what happens if you put dates into it.

```js
const dateNoon = '1/1/2021 12:00';
const dateMidnight = '1/1/2021 00:00';
const dateOneNoon = '1/1/2021 13:30';
const dateOneMidnight = '1/1/2021 01:30';

const testDate = (dateString) => {
  var date = new Date(dateString);
  var hours =  date.getHours();
  var minutes =  date.getMinutes();
  var current = hours + (minutes / 60);
  console.log(current);
}

testDate(dateNoon);
testDate(dateMidnight);
testDate(dateOneNoon);
testDate(dateOneMidnight);
```